# Is there a logfile for the find command?

Tags: find

Accidentally executed `find . -type d -empty -delete` in home directory. Was wondering if there's a way to see the list of deleted items.

Comment: ~/.bash_sessions locate the log ID # of the executed command and you might be able to stack a trace on it.

Comment: @CJDana .bash_sessions isn't enabled by default on most systems.. I think that's an OSX only thing?

Comment: @cutrightjm Shoot, I think your right. Im on _OS Sierra 10.12 beta_ in development env, modified core so much that i forget which files were default.

Answer (score 3):

No; there is no log of the output of

```
find . -type d -empty -delete
```

On the plus side, many programs will recreate missing directories on demand, especially those that are well written.